# Limit to 10 number of annotations in mapkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, annotations, nsarray

I have all my annotations(as nsdictionnaries) in an array , and the users add them one by one by tapping on an icon. I want to make it impossible to add more annotations after adding 10 annotations (there is 110).

Is it here i have to make something?:

```
-(IBAction) plusButtonTapped: (id) sender {
NSDictionary *poiDict = [poiArray objectAtIndex:nextPoiIndex++];
CLLocationCoordinate2D poiCoordinate;
poiCoordinate.latitude = [[poiDict valueForKey:@"workingCoordinate.latitude"] doubleValue];
poiCoordinate.longitude = [[poiDict valueForKey:@"workingCoordinate.longitude"] doubleValue];
MyMapAnnotation *poiAnnotation = [[MyMapAnnotation alloc]
                                  initWithCoordinate:poiCoordinate
                                  title:[poiDict valueForKey:@"Subtitle"]
                                  color:MKPinAnnotationColorRed ];
[mapView addAnnotation:poiAnnotation];
[self adjustMapZoom];
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance,

teddafan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a mutable array of annotations. Check the length when the button is clicked or disable the button when over your threshhold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How would you disable the button?

Comment: Docs for UIButton are pretty awesome and clear:

[yourButton setEnabled: NO];
or
yourButton.enabled = NO;